# To what voltage will this capacitor charge?

Tags: capacitor, charge

[image]

To what voltage will the capacitor in the circuit here above charge?

The circuit is fed by 10V DC.

I=U/R=10/100k=0.1mA

Voltage drop on the 10k is 1V.

Will the capacitor charge to 9V or to 10V?

Someone told me that if I connect a high power probe to a high voltage point without connecting it to a scope first, the voltage can fry the capacitor in its correction circuit. I have no idea how he came to that, the probe has 1M ohm / 100k divider, and so the final voltage on the capacitors is just very little. That's why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

One way to look at this is is to redraw it a little, and see if we can't simplify it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3Cg8k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've just swapped the positions of R2 and C1, but since they are in parallel, there's no functional difference.

The first thing that occurs to me here is that the system of V1, R1 and R2 (in the blue box) can be reduced to their Thevenin equivalent:

$$ R_{TH} = R_1 \parallel R_2 = \frac{10k\Omega \times 90k\Omega}{10k\Omega + 90k\Omega} = 9k\Omega $$

$$ V_{TH} = V_1 \frac {R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = 10V \times \frac{90k\Omega}{10k\Omega + 90k\Omega} = 9V $$

The circuit becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh5XmN.png)</sup>

Suddenly the answer to your question pops out; obviously the capacitor will charge to 9V.

The initial current that will flow through C1 is also clear. Assuming the capacitor is initially discharged, with 0V across it, then the whole 9V must be across \$R_{TH}\$, and by Ohm's law:

$$ I(t=0) = \frac{9V}{9k\Omega} = 1mA $$

On top of that, we also see exactly what will be the time constant of the charging curve:

$$ \tau = R_{TH} \times C_1 $$

Thevenin for the win. Again.

Comment: Thank you Simon.

Answer (score 1):

I'll not answer the question but I'll show the way.

The circuit is basically a voltage divider having the capacitor at the output. So you should be able to make a Thevenin conversion to the 10k-90k network, and workout the rest again. That'll make the things easier.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the cap charge to 9V or to 10V?

9V.

> Someone told me that if I connect a high power probe to a high voltage point without connecting it to a scope first, the voltage can fry the capacitor in its correction circuit.

I don't know about "frying the capacitor". However, this situation is slightly different from the example with the 10k and 90k above. A standard oscilloscope has a 1 M\$\Omega\$ input resistance. A 10x probe is likely to have a 9M internal resistance. The circuit with the probe plugged into the oscilloscope might be modeled something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flw1DW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the oscilloscope connected, C1 will only charge to 10 V. But with the oscilloscope disconnected, C1 will charge to 100 V.

Comment: This makes sense. My probe has 100k in parallel with the cap so the caps cannot be fried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know what a Thevenin equivalent circuit is, you can answer your question with only Ohm's Law and some thinking.

Initially, the voltage across the cap is 0 V.  When power is first applied, the cap begins charging up.  Eventually, depending on the value of the cap, the circuit will stabilize with some voltage across the cap.  At this point, there is no current through the cap because it is charged up as high as it's going to get.

Since there is no current through the cap, it can be disconnected without changing the voltage at the node between the two resistors.  Now you can solve for the voltage across each resistor with Ohm's Law, and this gives you the voltage across the cap.

Note:  To make discussions such as this, and your own math, more clear, add a unique reference designator to each component, such as R1, R2, C1, etc.  This will eliminate a common source of confusion and mistakes.

Comment: Well put. Thank you, this is what i did, because i really forgot the Thevenin theorem, and my conclusion was the cap charges up to 9V. I had been confused with someone else's opinion as stated in the OP, and i needed to make it straight. You are right about the designators, this is my first post here :). I am going to learn Thevenin again, that is for sure.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem

Answer (score -1):

Well, notice that we can write an equation for the voltage across the capacitor using the current divider formula and Laplace transform:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2+\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{s}}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\left(\text{R}_2\space\text{||}\space\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}}\right)}}_{\text{input current}}}_{\text{current divider}}\right]_{\left(t\right)}\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\alpha\space\text{||}\space\beta:=\frac{\displaystyle\alpha\beta}{\displaystyle\alpha+\beta}\$.

Which, gives:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_2\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle t\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2\right)}{\displaystyle\text{CR}_1\text{R}_2}\right)\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag2$$

So, when \$\displaystyle t\to\infty\$ we get:

$$\lim_{t\space\to\space\infty}\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_2\left(1-0\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}=\frac{\displaystyle\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{R}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2}\tag3$$

Comment: <Note: This is not in any way a dig at the TS>  Do you really think that someone who barely comprehends Ohm's Law and does not know what a Thevenin equivalent is will learn anything from Laplace equations?  Really?  Performing and teaching are not the same thing.

Comment: Indeed. I was about to say how much more complex it could get to come up with the formula for a simple voltage divider. Where did you define what û sub i is for the OP? I don't recall seeing that notation for voltage source elsewhere, by the way.

Comment: Well, I do not agree. Based on the other answers, my answer provides a mathematical approach. If my answer was the only one I can understand the points you both try to make.